SignalR Hub URL Returns Fallback HTML Instead of JSON on Production Server
I am currently developing a project using ASP.NET Core with SignalR. Everything works fine locally: my SignalR hub is reached as expected and behaves correctly. However, when I deploy the application to the production server, the SignalR hub URL unexpectedly returns a fallback HTML page instead of the expected JSON response.
Bellow the code fo Hub.
    public class NotificationHub: Hub
    {
        private readonly ILogger<NotificationHub> _logger;

        public NotificationHub(ILogger<NotificationHub> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
            var userId = httpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, userId);
            }
            _logger.LogInformation("Connection established. ConnectionId: {ConnectionId}", Context.ConnectionId);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }


        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
            var userId = httpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, userId);
            }
            _logger.LogInformation("Connection disconnected. ConnectionId: {ConnectionId}, Exception: {Exception}", Context.ConnectionId, exception?.Message);
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }


    }

That is the Error "Failed to complete negotiation with the server: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!--  --> "... is not valid JSON"
It comes with Statuscode 200, so I didnt see any Log about it. I have used the Log for SignalR, but I can only see the log local. On the server there is no Info about connection and SignalR.
And that is the IIS log.
2024-06-05 09:01:22 10.10.7.51 POST /Webex handler=Connect 80 - 10.55.30.80 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/125.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/125.0.0.0 http://myaddress/Webex 200 0 0 593
2024-06-05 09:01:22 10.10.7.51 POST /notificationHub/negotiate negotiateVersion=1 80 - 10.55.30.80 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/125.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/125.0.0.0 http://myaddress/Webex?handler=Connect 200 0 0 14

My server doesn't support Websocket, but It's not the reson why it return the fallback error page.
Thanks a lot.
i have checked for any URL rewrite rules that might redirect or transform requests.
Ensured that the application's routing configuration is identical to the local setup.
I am not sure what might be causing this behavior on the production server that differs from the local setup. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or can anyone provide insights into what might be going wrong?

In your production server, there are many things we need to check, but first, we should know what the html says in the error message, something like 401 or 500. So please check my sample code to check the html content.

And we also should check the rewrite ruls in your IIS.

Thank you for your help.It returns 200, so that I was confused and didn't recognize the URL was wrong. It turned out that the application was implemented in an app pool and the URL in  hud should be fully configured, with the part of APP pool.
